# How to extract text before the last space in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple values from a string column, some values have one space, others have two spaces, example:

```
Ohio St. Buckeyes
Youngstown St. Penguins
Akron Zips
Houston Cougars
Duke Blue Devils
```

How would I run code to achieve just the school names and not the mascot name?

```
Ohio St.
Youngstown St.
Duke
Akron
Houston
```

Comment: You have to read line by line and split every line by space into array. Then get first item in array or list.

Comment: [`rsplit()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) is better. Specifically `df['team'].str.rsplit(' ', 1, expand=True) [0]` is a one-liner. We rsplit into two new columns, and keep just the lefthand one. cc: @BrainFlooder

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
import re

for i in df["team"]:
    print(re.findall(r"\w+", i)[0])
```

and you'll get your last row's value/string

Comment: This is not efficient, there is a vectorial function: `str.extract`

Comment: @smci have you compared the timings? Not sure that is as you need to read two `str` access, and this won't work if you have more than one date

Comment: `str.rsplit()`or `str.extract()` are both better than iterating and calling a regex on each line, like this.

Comment: (@mozway: that's what I was trying to say the first time)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = ['Duke Blue Devils', 'Akron Zips']
ls = [x.split() for x in df ]
print((ls[0][0]), (ls[1][0]))
```